# SSIM is high, MSE is low but the two images are not similar

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-image, mse, ssim

I want to calculate the similarity between these two images:

[image: original]

and

[image: reconstructed]

These are brain topography maps and colors inside the circle represent the area being activated while watching TV. Thus **I am looking for a metric which computes the similarity between original and reconstructed image taking into account how much they are similar with respect the "activated" areas**. As you can see the two images are not very similar since, in the original image, the activated area is left-side while in the reconstructed one the activated area is right-side.

For doing that, I am combining both [SSIM](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.metrics.html#skimage.metrics.structural_similarity) (scaled between 0 and 1) and [MSE](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.metrics.html#skimage.metrics.mean_squared_error) using this formula:

```
ssim = scaled_ssim(original_image, reconstructed_image)  # between 0 and 1
mse = mean_squared_error(original_image, reconstructed_image)
score = ssim / (mse + 1)
```

where `scaled_ssim` is defined as follows:

```
def scaled_ssim(original, reconstructed):
    original = normalize(original)
    reconstructed = normalize(reconstructed)
    score = ssim(original, reconstructed, data_range=1, channel_axis=-1)
    return (score + 1) / 2
```

And I am getting:

```
ssim on random test sample: 0.5712
mse on random test sample: 0.0004
score on random test sample: 0.5710
```

As you can notice, the `score` is `0.5710`. Can you suggest me a metric which performs better, that is takes into account the activation areas of the "brain"?

Comment: Something like the Earth mover's distance might be applicable. See if this answer is helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/404915

Comment: @Anonymous It seemed not to be helpful.